# Add one hour to Access table field, and save the value in another field

Tags: ms-access, time, vba

I have a table ("Bookings") with the field [StartHour] (I get its value from a form). I want to automatically update the value of another table field ([EndHour]) with the value [StartHour]+1hour.
How can I do this?

I found some VBA (I suppose) solutions, but I don't think I can use VBA in here. I'm talking about

```
= DateAdd("h", 1, [YourField])
```

Comment: If you are dealing with two tables then you have to have VBA involved at some stage.

Comment: If the below answer has helped, please give it a tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is not tested and im writing it from off the top of my head so there might be a few issues. But if you put it into the VBA editor it will show any

You'll need the microsoft DAO reference library ticked in tools>references

Open both tables in memory then edit the first record of the endhour field.
Add 1 hour to the start hour of the first table, then save in end hour field.

```
dim tbl1 as dao.recordset
dim tbl2 as dao.recordset

tbl1 = currentdb.openrecordset("table1")
tbl2 = currentdb.openrecordset("table2")

with tbl2
    .edit
    .fields("EndHour") =  dateadd("h",1,tbl1("Start Hour"))
    .update
end with

set tbl1 = nothing
set tbl2 = nothing
```